# How to show that $Z = |X|$ and $-|X|$ has a a standard normal distribution? ($X \sim$ Folded standard normal distributed)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given the probability density function of $X$ (folded standard normal distributed) is:

$$f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right),\quad x \geqslant 0 $$

How can one show that $Z = |X|$ with probability $1/2$ and $Z=-|X|$ with probability $1/2$ has a standard normal distribution?

Please give me a **hint only**. Thanks!

(I tried to show that E(Z) = 0 and Var(Z) = 1, but it was not sufficient.)

Comment: ANYTHING works. What did you try?

Comment: Could you please give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Which word do you fail to understand in "What did you try"?

Comment: For example what happens when you take the absolute value of a random variable?

Comment: I tried to show E(Z) = 0 and Var(Z) = 1 but realized that they together do not mean that Z has a standard normal distribution. Now I am looking for another hint to start with the proof.

Comment: I also tried: Prob(Z < z) = Prob(|X| < z) = Prob(-z < X < z) = Prob(X < z) - Prob(X < -z) = F(z) - F(-z) = 0.5. However, I did not know where that would lead me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints

- Since the density of $X$ has zero mass on the negative real line, we have, with probability 1, that  $X \ge 0$. So you can discard the absolute value sign around $X$. That is, $Z = X$ or $-X$ with equal probability. More precisely, there is a symmetric Bernoulli variable
  $$
   B \sim 
  \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{with probability}\; 1/2 \\
  1 & \text{with probability}\; 1/2
  \end{cases}
  $$
  which is independent of $X$ and $Z = B X + (1-B)(-X)$. (This a more detailed description of for how $Z$ is constructed from $X$.)
- You can now use the law of total probability. For any (measurable!) subset of the real-line (say $A=(-\infty,x]$), we have
  $$
  P (Z \in A) = P(X \in A|B = 0) P(B = 0) + P(-X \in A| B = 1) P(B = 1)
  $$
  You should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: You are welcome.